# Rich Push Notification in AWS swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am Using AWS SNS for push notification.

when i try to use Notification service and Notification content for rich push notification

i am receiving notification but its not hitting didReceive function

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {

            var urlString:String? = nil
            if let urlImageString = request.content.userInfo["urlImageString"] as? String {
                urlString = urlImageString
            }

            if urlString != nil, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString!) {
                print("fileUrl: \(fileUrl)")

                guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: fileUrl) else {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: "image.jpg", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
                    print("error in UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk()")
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }

                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [ attachment ]
            }

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
```

my request in aws console as raw is

```
{
    "APNSMessage": {
        "aps": {
            "body": "Hello",
            "title": "One Touch",
            "category": "rich-apns",
            "mutable-content": 1,
            "content-available" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one guide me move through...

Comment: check target isn't as your device ?

Comment: I am using real device for checking. Can you explain briefly what are you saying @Sh_Khan .